# Join a few elements of the list in Python

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, transformer-model

Please have a look into the code below

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2Model

text = "Here is the sentence I want embeddings for."
#marked_text = "[CLS] " + text + " [SEP]"
# Tokenize our sentence with the GPT2 tokenizer.
tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
print(tokenized_text)
```

Output of the above code is shown below :-

```
['Here', 'Ġis', 'Ġthe', 'Ġsentence', 'ĠI', 'Ġwant', 'Ġembed', 'd', 'ings', 'Ġfor', '.']
```

But I want an output like this:-

```
['Here', 'Ġis', 'Ġthe', 'Ġsentence', 'ĠI', 'Ġwant', 'Ġembeddings', 'Ġfor', '.']
```

So, while tokenizing the text, the tokenizer has splitted the word 'embeddings' because it doesn't have this word in its dictionary. But, I don't want this happening. I want the whole word 'embedding' to be tokenized as it is.

I don't know how to solve this. Also kindly note that tokenized_text is a List object.
Please help.

**EDIT 1 :**
I came with this solution

```
tokenized_text[6:9] = [''.join(tokenized_text[6:9])]
print(tokenized_text)
```

And it gave me the desired output as well but I don't want to give the numbers here specifically. I want the machine to figure it out for itself.
Like whichever element in the list doesn't start with that 'G' special character, that element needs to be joined with the previous element and so on.

**EDIT 2 :**
I came across another approach and here's the code for it, but it doesn't work probably because of wrong for loops.

```
for i in range(1, len(tokenized_text)):
  if tokenized_text[i].startswith('Ġ'):
    i += 1 
  else:
    for j in range(i, len(tokenized_text)):
      if tokenized_text[j].startswith("Ġ") :
        pass
      else :
        j += 1


tokenized_text[i-1:j] = [''.join(tokenized_text[i-1:j])]
print(tokenized_text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably no need of nested `for loops` here.
This code below works completely fine.

```
for i in range(1, len(tokenized_text)):
  if tokenized_text[i].startswith('Ġ'):
    i += 1 
  else :
    break

for j in range(i, len(tokenized_text)):
  if tokenized_text[j][0] in "Ġ.!?,":
    break
  else :
    j += 1

tokenized_text[i-1:j] = [''.join(tokenized_text[i-1:j])]
```